# MS Teams Graph API returns 'from' field as null when sending emails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a channel in the MS Teams where I want to send emails.

When I send email via gmail/outlook then in the response of the request (`GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/{id}`) the `from` field is `null`. I need to get `from` and `to` metadata as I process them in the Power Automate.

If I post a message directly via Teams App then it works fine, but with mails Teams have a trouble.

Any suggestions on what could be the problem and if is this even possible? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "send email via gmail/outlook"? Teams channel messages aren't emails and AFAIK there's no way to send email via the Teams methods in the Graph API

Comment: Well each channel in Teams has an email address where I can send email to. Via Graph API I just wanted to fetch who sent the email, but as I said the 'from' field is null.

Comment: Are you sending the mail from a personal account?

Comment: Yes, what account should I send it from?

Comment: Hi @H. Hasin - I am able to repro the issue. Taking this for internal discussion with team and will update you if it is by design or not.

Answer (score 1):

We have raised a bug for this issue and concerned team is working on it.